# How to execute parser delegate first in UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: xml, swift, parsing, soap

I am new to swift programming language, i am trying to use the `NSXMLParserDelegate` to parse an `xml` from a `soap` web service connection, the connection is working perfectly:

```
    struct Datos {
       let nombre:String
       let numero:String
    }

    var data = [Supervisor_Agencia]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       print("viewload")           

       var soapMessage = "...The xml message..."

       var urlString = "...The web service url..."
       var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
       var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

       request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
       request.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       request.addValue("...The Host...", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
       request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       request.addValue(String(soapMessage.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
       request.addValue("...The SOAP Action...", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

       var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
       connection!.start()
       if (connection == true) {
          var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
       }
    }
```

The parser delegate does its job and parses the info:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {/*The code*/}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {/*The code*/}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
 print("parser")
 cont = cont + 1
 data.append(Supervisor_Agencia(nombre: descripcion, numero: resultado))}
```

The problem is that when i tried to use the array "data" to make the cells i realize that the function parse executes at last, after the method tableView, so i cant use the array because it`s not filled yet:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("cont")
    return cont
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cells")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celda", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

   var dat : Supervisor_Agencia

    dat = data[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = dat.nombre

    return cell
}
```

I know this because the output order of the "print" is this:

1.viewload 2.cont 3.cells 4.parser

and i need that order be like this:

1.viewload 2.parser 3.cont 4.cells

Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that a web request does not come back at a time you can determine. Once your `parser` function returns the results, call `self.tableView.reloadData()`, and it will then use `data` properly to fill in your `tableView`, calling all the delegates as needed.

Before that happens, the easiest thing to do is to either create a `data` placeholder that is an empty array, which will then return `0` for number of rows and sections (and therefore you won't have to worry about `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it won't be called.